# How can I link two meshes with many vertices together to prevent lagging?

Tags: mesh, objects, edit-mode

I was recently asked to make a terrain in Blender. I thought, "no problem. I could just make a very large grid and use proportional editing to make different hills and cliffs. Simple".

The problem is my computer crashes, the number of required vertices was too large, so I decided to create multiple different objects, with same amount of vertex, so it had less to compute when in *Edit Mode*.

If I put the squares right next to each other, it made the same amount of area I wanted before, and the computer woundn't crash.

[image]

However I cannot join them together and enter edit mode for both at the same time; it crashes Blender. But when I edit one, the other stays exactly the same, and it looks like separate planes. I want it to look like one connected ground.

Note in the picture above both planes are exactly the same.

What I need to find out is how I can connect these vertices on the plane next to it, without requiring they enter edit mode together, as if one object. I just want them connected at certain locations, not joined and merged.

[image]

I was wondering if it would be possible with the *Hook* operator (which I don't know very well), or if it would require something else.

I just want it so when moving one vertex up one one shape moves it up on the other so it's not only rising on half of the ground.

Please tell me if this isn't well enough explained.

Comment: I think you mean Topography (as in terrain), not Typography (as in text fonts), right? Having the same amount of geometry distributed for more objects is generally worse for scene performance, even if it makes entering edit mode easier in that particular object. If it crashes you are exceeding your computer capabilities, you have to lower the number of subdivisions, there is no way around that. Using hooks and tricks will only make it worse.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Yes I did mean topography (stupid autocorrect). Thanks for the info, I guess my next question would be is it my CPU or RAM (or both) that would need upgraded to do more of this?

Comment: Before you spend any money that you may regret make sure you are not hitting Blender's performance limitations themselves. Some times even with an unlimited amount of RAM there is only so much software can handle. How are you making said terrain, sculpting, displacement, manual modelling?
Have you tried using modifiers to subdivide your mesh instead? Do you really need that high number of divisions, have you tried lower? You could probably get away with a lower poly mesh then add a *Subsurf* modifier afterwards for smoothing.

Comment: That may help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75704/how-to-create-a-seamless-low-poly-terrain-with-displace-and-multiple-planes/75712#75712.