# Merging an irregular surface into a plane

Tags: modeling

I have a few meshes full of bumps and holes that look like this:
[image: Surface Example]

I want to modify this surface to fit within a plane so that it will look something like this:

[image]

I'm not sure where to go about starting this, though. I just want the edges to be perfectly rectangular, so I can line up several of these side by side to get one big surface where the interface between them nice and straight. Any insight on how I could approach this would be helpful!

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75704/how-to-create-a-seamless-low-poly-terrain-with-displace-and-multiple-planes

Comment: This might suit your needs: Assuming the second image is of the bumpy object in the first image and a plane, i would add a Boolean modifier with Operation: Union on the plane. Then as Object target the bumpy object, Apply the modifier, and then delete all the vertices south of the plane.